# I Need to Insert a multiple tables data into single table using below code i tried but i have error

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, dynamic-sql

**If i type my source tables name, data are copy into our target table:**

```
'Create or Replace procedure p
(source_tab varchar2,target_tab varchar2)
As   
  query varchar2(200);
  Type I_tab is table of varchar2(100000) index by binary_integer;
  Rec_i I_tab;
Begin
  query=’select * from’||source_tab;
  Execute immediate query bulk collect into rec_i;
  Forall i in rec_i.first..rec_i.last
    Execute immediate’insert into’||target_tab||’values’||rec_i(i);
  Commit;
End;
/
```

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us *what* error you get? Why does the title ask about multiple tables, you only have one source table? Why are you using `execute immediate` for this? Or even any PL/SQL at all?

Comment: In addition to the errors noted in @APC's post below, there is also a problem in line 8 where you have written `query=`. The assignment operator in PL/SQL is `:=` and should be used instead of `=` in this line. Additionally, in line 1 there is a single-quote at the start of the line which shouldn't be there. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of anything useful like the actual compilation or runtime errors are we can do is guess.

As it happens your code has several obvious bloomers.

1. You appear to be using MS Word type smart quotes `’` whereas Oracle expects regular ASCII dumb quotes `'`.  So that would be a compilation error.
2. The maximum size of a VARCHAR2 is 32767 so your nested table statement will hurl a compilation error.
3. You need to put spaces around the key words in the dynamic SQL.  Otherwise you'll get a runtime error.  So `’insert into’||target_tab||’values’` needs to `'insert into '||target_tab||' values '` .  Make sure you check all the strings.
4. In PL/SQL the assignment operator is `:=`; `=` is the test for equality.

Less obvious, but we can't use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in a FORALL.  It's not a programmatic loop, and it needs to be a DML (SQL) statement: EXECUTE IMEMDIATE is PL/SQL.  However you can do the same thing with

```
execute immediate
    'insert into '|| target_tab ||
   ' select * from '|| source_tab
```